# Как собрать jar?

Tags: java, jar

На сервере настроил крон и команду для запуска jar. Нужно собрать jar из исходников. Исходник - это один класс Main.java и библиотека JSOUP. Как и что делать?

Comment: обязательно собирать это в jar? если у вас один класс, то и запускайте его, а необходимые библиотеки добавьте в classpath.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman, как это запускать один класс?

Comment: запустить можно так `java -cp <путь к jar с JSOUP>:/. Main`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
javac -cp jsoup-1.10.2.jar -d . Main.java
jar cf JarName.jar path/to/Main.class
```

Comment: Как запускать я знаю, а как именно собрать джар?

Comment: Первая команда компилирует, вторая упаковывает результат компиляции в jar. При чём тут запуск?

Comment: Ой, спасибо. А почему jar так мало весит? Jsoup нет

Comment: Jar включающий в себя содержимое других jar'ов называется fat jar. Чтобы его сделать, надо распаковать jsoup в тот же каталог, куда компилировался ваш Main.java, командой `jar xf jsoup.jar`, а потом упаковать всё вместе. Но fat jar стоит использовать только тогда, когда другого выхода совсем нет. Мало того, что они утяжеляют дистрибутив и нивелируют модульность, так они ещё и могут приводить к конфликтам и усложняют процесс обновления. Поэтому лучше положить jsoup.jar рядом с вашим jar-файлом и запускать командой `java -cp /path/to/jars/*` package.name.Main`